# Does the expiration status of an issuer's certificate affect a subject's expiration?

Tags: security, ssl, certificate

If a certificate issuer issues a certificate that has an expiration that occurs after the expiration of the issuer's own certificate, will the issued certificate still be valid after the issuer's certificate has expired?

To be more clear, let me give an example:
I = The Issuer
C = The issued certificate

if I created C in 2007 with an expiration date of 2017
and I's certificate expires in 2010
will C's certificate be valid in 2012?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clients should check each certificate in the chain for validity. So, if you have a root that issues a certificate to a signing CA which issues your identify certificate, your client would need to check to ensure that your identity certificate is valid (still in valid date period and not revoked), then your signing CA's certificate is valid (still in valid date period and not revoked), and then the root (still in valid date period and not revoked and, hopefully, be in your trust store as that's the only way you would trust this chain anyway).

So, basically, every certificate in the chain must remain valid for your certificate to be valid. If the issuer's certificate expires before the issued certificate, the issued certificate should not be valid.

Answer (score 5):

Just to give an authorative source for what the others have already said:
[RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-6.1.3) states in section 6.1.3

> The basic path processing actions to be performed for certificate i
> (for all i in [1..n]) are listed below.

One of these actions is to verify (2)

> The certificate validity period includes the current time.

The notion of current time is interesting here - for example, if in 2012 you receive a document that was signed in 2010 and additionally carries a RFC3161 timestamp on it, then the signature is to be considered valid, because both I and C were valid at the "current time" (2010). Without the timestamp, however, you would have to reject the signature because lacking cryptographically reliable information on the time of signing, your only chance is to assume "now" as the "current time"; and in 2012, I was no longer valid.

Comment: if a subject has a timestamp for a valid issuer certificate, but after the issuer expired it was reissued and then the reissued certificate is revoked, will the subject still be valid?